# Sitefinity How to Exlude Template from Searching

Tags: sitefinity

Is there any way to exclude Sitefinity main template i used for all the pages, from searching?
Right now if i search,the search is returning the result with words present in the template menu,even though its not belong to the page.

Now i need to search pages exlceding that template contents.

Thanks in Advance.

The problem here is i have added a menu inside a content block widget in a template.
This template is used throughout the site and when i search for a keyword using the search feature, all the pages of the website are listed in the search result because the keyword is also found in the menu.So i need a solution so that the search result does not include the menu content in the search result.
This is a very high priority. Please help me find a solution at the earliest possible.

Answer (score 2):

Ivan Pelovski recently published a blog post on how you can hide content from the search engine by using custom layout controls. Not specifically what you are asking, but maybe it can help.

Here: http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/ivanpelovski/posts/12-02-06/hiding_page_content_from_the_search_engine_in_sitefinity_using_layout_widgets.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a robots.txt metatag like this into the top of the template:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
```

In more recent versions of Sitefinity you can also uncheck a box at each page level that will prevent the page from being indexed. The column for this setting in the database is sf_page_data (table) .. crawlable (column) in case you want to write a sql script to update several pages at once.

The exclusion of templates from search is mentioned in more detail here: 
http://www.sitefinity.com/devnet/forums/sitefinity-4-x/general-discussions/exclude-page-from-search-index.aspx

Note that this will probably also prevent other search engines (such as google) from indexing that page.

Comment: Thank you for your response.However this is not what i was looking for.
The problem here is i have added a menu inside a content block widget in a template.
This template is used throughout the site and when i search for a keyword using the search feature, all the pages of the website are listed in the search result because the keyword is also found in the menu.So i need a solution so that the search result does not include the menu content in the search result.
This is a very high priority. Please help me find a solution at the earliest possible.